# I have Nissan Altima 2013 model S, not sure what type of disks will play in the factory fitted disk player

Tags: nissan

I have Nissan Altima 2013 model S, not sure what type of disks will play in the factory fitted disk player. As it is not having any logos on it mentioning as MP3 or DVD, not sure which type of disks will be played.

Answer (score 2):

[You can find your answer in the owner's guide.](https://owners.nissanusa.com/content/techpub/ManualsAndGuides/Altima/2013/2013-Altima-owner-manual.pdf) Check page 196 of the pdf –

Answer (score 1):

The drivers handbook for your car will allow you to correctly identify what radio installation you have. It will also outline its features, what discs you can use and how. The screen on the installation is for displaying information of the radios settings, your preferances and service information, and on some sets GPS. If fitted, it will also display the images from your parking/rear view camera. It is not a DVD player in the sense that you can drive along the road watching a movie. Check out the vehicles handbook.